# Can you suggest a 0 to 10 Volts mesuring unit with an easy .NET (C#) API?

Tags: electrical-engineering, measurements

I am looking for a voltage input module that measures a voltage input in the range of 0 to 10 Volts (slowly changing during a 5 seconds period). It should be connected to a local Windows computer that has a preexisting .NET (C#) software program (with its source code available) for plotting the input. I am completely inexperienced in this area of device acquisition, so I find it difficult to select the device model that would fit the purpose, and, confirm the existence of the accompanying .NET API.

For example, if I select a USB voltage input module from Lucid Control company, they offer these two downloads (scroll below to see the API + .Net examples) that do not seem to function. The supplied .dll file cannot be added to the project. The documentation is lacking.
https://www.lucid-control.com/downloads/

That shows that a solid device recommendation is needed to accommodate an easy update of the program code using the provided API.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gianni, welcome to engineering. a) This is a resource hunting question which will probably won't be releant to other users, and b) its probably best answered in Electronics Stack Exchange

Comment: ...migrating...

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Labjack](https://labjack.com/support/software/examples/ljm/net). They are relatively cost effective solutions, with good documentation (I've primarily used python though).

They come in different configurations.